# How to automate counting of specific word in a slack channel?

Tags: javascript, slack

I have a script that will send set’s of variables to a slack channel via a webhook url that will tell me which site clicked or used my script. My question is, is there a way I can count these sites via automation or a script as well to avoid counting it manually? If this is possible in Slack or Javascript, I would really appreciate your help. Thank you very much in advance.

I have not tried any scripting yet but I couldn’t find any hint or sample on the internet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.